# Integration of Rational function.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have this problem
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}dx$$

This is problem from IITJEE 2000 Paper 1

I tried following steps

I tried using few properties but I know only few of them hence no luck there.

$\tan\theta = x $ but still stuck.

Integration by Parts still got nothing.

And Partial fractions. Still no help. Can anyone help me out. And also share the methodology for solving similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: Use long division to write integrand as $p(x)+(ax+b)/(1+x^2)$ with $p(x)$ a polynomial.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yeah, it worked out !

Comment: This integral is noted for its surpring bottom-line answer.

Comment: For the record, for others than the original poster who may be reading this, we have $$ x^4(1-x)^4 = x^4 - 4x^5 + 6x^6 - 4x^7 + x^8, $$ and then long division is applied to that, dividing it by $x^2+1. \qquad$

Comment: Such integral is well-known to be $\frac{22}{7}-\pi$. It is the classical way for proving the Archimedean approximation of $\pi$ through Beuker-like integrals: you just have to perform a polynomial division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial fractions should work. Long division gives that
$$
\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}=x^6-4x^5+5x^4-4x^2-\frac{4}{1+x^2}.
$$
Integration of the polynomial portion should be straight forward and use the fact that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(\arctan x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
for the rest.

Comment: Sniped me, but this is correct.

Comment: You sure about the -16 over the last term?

Comment: You don't need partial fractions here, nor does your answer use them.

Comment: the answer turns out to be 22/7 - pi !

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x^2}=Q(x) +\frac {a + bx}{1+x^2} .$$

Where $Q(x) $ is a polynomial.

The $$ \frac {a + bx}{1+x^2}$$ is also integrated easily.